# Hide div after scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page where it has a main body for posts but at the click of a link, it'll scroll into view a hidden div. my question is how do i hide the div after scrolling past it or once it is out of ViewPort because my current jQuery code isn't working at all.

**here's my code :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.about').hide();
  $('.link2about').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.about').show();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.about').offset().top
    }, 1000, 'swing');
    return false;
  });
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('.about').is(':visible')) {
      $('.about').show();
    } else {
      $('.about').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link2about"> about </div>
<div class="posts">
  body content here body content here body content here body content here body content here body content here body content here body content here body content here body content here body content here body content here
</div>
<div class="about">
  about content here about content here about content here about content here about content here about content here
</div>
```

Comment: Why you showing "if ($('.about').is(':visible')) { $('.about').show();} else {      $('.about').hide(); }" means when $('.about') visible then you show it again, why?

Comment: Seems like an odd thing to hide it after scrolling off screen, this makes the document jump. Why not just have it visible and scroll to it on click but leave it alone if when you scroll away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `offset().top` to get `element` top, then use a statement to compare window `scrollTop` and element `offset top`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var elTop = $('.about').offset().top; // get element top

  $('.about').hide();
  $('.link2about').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.about').show();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.about').offset().top
    }, 1000, 'swing');
    return false;
  });
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > elTop) { // If window scroll top greater than element top
      $('.about').hide();
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.link2about {
  color: red;
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.about {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link2about"> about </div>
<div class="posts">
  body content here body content here body content here body content here body content here body content here body content here body content here body content here body content here body content here body content here
</div>
<div class="about">
  about content here about content here about content here about content here about content here about content here
</div>
```